# TFS 2012 Test test project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I need an open source (something like Contoso) test project, that can be deployed in Visual Studio 2012. The project must contain information that shows how to work with TFS. So, the project should contain **work items**, **source code**, **users**, etc.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show/see how working with VS and TFS 2012 I recommend to look at the VHD images provided by Microsoft.

They can be found in Brian Keller's blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/briankel/archive/2011/09/16/visual-studio-11-application-lifecycle-management-virtual-machine-and-hands-on-labs-demo-scripts.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but I need some test project (.sln) with source code.

Comment: The images contains full projects with source, test, database, builds etc. The images are used to do the Hands-on-Labs